# fwrite php, file is not really saved?

Tags: javascript, php, fwrite

I have a javascript file called in my webpage. It contains only one var :

```
var tab = [ "img1.jpg" ,
            "img2.jpg" ,
            .......... ,
            "img100.jpg"
          ]
```

`"img_i_.jpg"` in `tab` are from my data base.

I've written a php code to update this file.

```
...

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$script="var tab= [\n";

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
    $script .= "\t\"" . $r['name']"\",\n";

$script = $script."];\n";

$fileName = fopen("js/tab.js", "w");
fwrite($fileName, $script);
fclose($fileName);

...
```

When I check out my js file, all is correctly written, but when I reload my page, nothing has changed.

Curiously, when I edit that js file manually, and then save it then my webpage changes after reload.

Why ? And how to solve it ?  Thanks

Comment: Your browser might be caching the js file

Comment: but when I edit it manually, why is it not cached ?

Comment: Browsers do strange things with caching sometimes. Test this by putting a random string onto the end of your js include (which will remove any caching) - e.g. `<script src="js/yourfile.js?[generate_random_string_and_put_it_here]"></script>`

Comment: Do **NOT** generate JS code like this. You should be putting those filenames into an array and then `json_encoding()` that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be writing your file in a different location. Check the current directory under which the php page is run, and try to specify an absolute path to fopen rather than a relative one.

`dirname(realpath(__FILE__))` will return the path to the folder where the current php file is stored, so you can generate absolute paths through that.

Edit: I'd also suggest doing some error checking around fopen, so that you know if the file was really opened.

---

**Extra**

You should really change your `mysql_*` calls to at least `mysqli_*` or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php). The original mysql extension is old, doesn't support prepared statements and has been deprecated (and is due for removal).

Comment: wrong path ? no, because when I check out the updated file, all is correctly written

Comment: In that case it is a caching issue. Browsers have different policies. Usually though, if the cached file is too old or you directly request it, then it's reloaded, but not otherwise.

Comment: @scrowler comment would help with the caching issue.